# Grafana Only allow access signing in with Google oauth if member of certain group

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, grafana, google-workspace

After following this doc : https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/google/

I'm able to connect to my grafana by using google oauth2, now i would like that my user can connect only if he is a member of a certain group in google is that possible ?

So at the end you would have something like :

```
[auth.google]
enabled = true
client_id = CLIENT_ID
client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
scopes = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
auth_url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
token_url = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
allowed_domains = mycompany.com mycompany.org
allow_sign_up = true
allowed_groups = google-admins devs
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `[auth.google]` doesn't support authorization.

Better is to use `[auth.generic_oauth]` with properly configured [role mapping](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/#role-mapping) (where you can use groups) and `role_attribute_strict = true`.

Comment: We are using `role_attribute_strict = true` but it does not seem to block users without roles from login. Any ideas?